# Text not encoded properly

Tags: encoding, iso-8859-1

In my masterpage, I have the following in the header.

This allows me to put special characters into my website. The problem is that when javascript tries to load (on the client) special characters, I get that weird box.

Example url...

http://89.184.149.229/Sandportal/vinnan/trol-lna/monica-sakk--vikuskiftinum

Text is below the 4 stars (mid left).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common cause to that problem is that, although you *declare* your page as Latin1-encoded (ISO-8859-1), the file itself is not (eg. it might be encoded in Win-CP-1512 by default if you're on Windows).

Please ensure that all your files are properly encoded. Tools such as Notepad++ on Windows can help you spot this problem.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed notepad++, can you give me more direction on how to save the file in a certain encoding?